# .new is not assigning an id to the new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My ReportNu model is tied to an existing table whose unique id column is "oid". When I try to create a new report, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: null value in column "oid" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, 2, 2, 106341051, 2016, 0, 0, null, null).
```

I feel like there should be a way to tell rails to automatically set the oid for me, incrementing from 1 on up. How do I do that? I loaded up the rails console and ReportNu.new just creates an instance with an oid of nil.

Here are the relevant portions of my files.

report_nu.rb:

```
class ReportNu < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "t_report_cust"
  self.primary_key = "oid"
  ...
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@report_nu) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :cust_id, :value => current_user.id %><br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :spec_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :spec_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :hid %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :hid %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :fore_yr %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :fore_yr %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

reports_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @report_nu = ReportNu.new
  end

  def create
    @report_nu = ReportNu.new(report_nu_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @report_nu.save
        format.html { redirect_to @report_nu, notice: 'Report nu was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @report_nu }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @report_nu.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: .create will assign an id, if auto increment is done for the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nithin answered this for me in his comment above. The table I was working with did not have it's primary key set to auto-increment. I didn't create the table and didn't even know to look for that. Thanks Nithin! If you post your comment as an answer I'll check it and delete my own "answer"